# Qt Creator subproject just to copy files

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a Qt subproject which **only** contains directories with files (**no** source code). Those files are to be copied to the `build/bin` directory

```
QtProject
  subproject1 (contains code)
  subproject2 (only contains directories with files to be copied)
    files1
    files2
```

So far I have been using `QMAKE_PRE_LINK` and `QMAKE_PRE_LINK` to copy the files (**which works**). However, as the project template is `TEMPLATE = lib` I get compile warnings as there is no code to be generated (see bottom).

If I change to `TEMPLATE = subdirs` the copy is not triggered, as there is no link operation.

So how can I trigger the copy operation without any source code?

---

Compile errors with `TEMPLATE = lib`

```
:-1: warning: LNK4001: no object files specified; libraries used
:-1: warning: LNK4068: /MACHINE not specified; defaulting to X86
:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __DllMainCRTStartup@12
debug\blackresources.dll:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

---

copy which works, except for the above compile errors

```
QMAKE_PRE_LINK += $$COPY $$shell_path($$PWD/data) \
                      $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD/../bin/resources)
```

Answer (score 2):

Extra build steps are mentioned in a generic fashion in the documentation...

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets

```
mytarget.target = .buildfile
mytarget.commands = touch $$mytarget.target
mytarget.depends = mytarget2

mytarget2.commands = @echo Building $$mytarget.target
```

...

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget mytarget2
```

### Copying data files to the build directory with qmake

dragly spells it out nicely on his website.  I've copied over some chunks of it.

http://dragly.org/2013/11/05/copying-data-files-to-the-build-directory-when-working-with-qmake/

> ```
> copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) $$PWD/data $$OUT_PWD
> first.depends = $(first) copydata
> export(first.depends)
> export(copydata.commands)
> QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
> ```
>
> The meaning of the different names in the above are as follows:
>
> - `$(COPY_DIR)` – Holds a platform-dependent copy-command that makes sure to copy recursively.
> - `$$PWD` – Holds the name of the source code directory, where your .pro file resides.
> - `$$OUT_PWD` – Holds the name of the build directory. Note that this may not work if you are running qmake and make in the same directory
>     as your source code, as you will be copying into the same folder as
>     you copy from.
> - `copydata` – Just a name we choose. You can replace this with whatever you want.
> - `first` – This is a build step that already exists in the Makefile generated by qmake. We attach the copy build step to this build step.
>     export – Makes the variable in the argument of the function available
>     in a global scope.
> - `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` – Tells qmake that you want to build more targets than the ones it adds by default to the Makefile. This method
>     is a bit messy, and I wish the Qt developers would make it easier to
>     do this, but it works. It also ensures that the data is always copied,
>     ensuring that any changes in the data folder are pushed to the build
>     folder.

On Windows, I personally like `robocopy` for all of my mirroring needs.  And on linux/mac, it is hard to go wrong with `rsync`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good hint, but suffers from the same problem as above. `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata` depends on the "first" buildtstep. That in turn requires `TEMPLATE = lib` to be present, which again results in the above mentioned error messages.

So all the solutions so far require me to build something, which is not there (as the subproject only contains files)

Comment: Instead of creating a subproject, make a pri file and put this code in that.

Comment: I will do the following for now. I create a `pri`file for the subproject (containing the copy operation),include it in one of the code subprojects `.pro`file and trigger it from there.